# RecyclerView onScrolled method of addOnScrollListener not called except only once

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

## Background:

I am implementing pagination logic with `RecyclerView` by adding `addOnScrollListener` function.

## Problem faced:

The `onScrolled` method is called once when the RecyclerView adapter is loaded with **dy** value of 0. However when the list reaches its end when scrolled, the `onScrolled` method is not triggered while the `onScrollStateChanged` is triggered correctly.

**Here is my Adapter:**

```
HistoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HistoryItem> items, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                Timber.w("onScrolled.. %s", dy);

                if (dy > 0) {
                    totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                    Timber.e("totalItemCount: %s", totalItemCount);
                    Timber.e("lastVisibleItem: %s", lastVisibleItem);

                    if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + 1)) {

                        Timber.i("End reached...");
                        if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                            //Log.i(TAG, "Episodes Adapter: onLoadMore calling...");
                            onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                        }
                        isLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            }
        });
    }
```

**Recycler:**

```
private void setupRecycler() {
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        historyAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(getActivity(), historyItems, recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
        historyAdapter.setClickListener(this);
        historyAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(this);
        historyAdapter.setErrorClickListener(this);
    }
```

**My Recycler xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/medium_text_color_blue"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="#"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4.5"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="CLASS"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="time"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_reflection_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="No Reflection History found!" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/history_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

## What I have researched:

There are many such issues already posted at StackOverflow but most of them point to a solution that is to remove the parent `ScrollView` of the `RecyclerView` which is stopping the `onScrolled` method to be triggered, however this seems to be not an issue I am facing.

[RecyclerView.onScrolled() not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632796/recyclerview-onscrolled-not-getting-called)

[RecyclerView onScrolled not called when use scrollToPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686356/recyclerview-onscrolled-not-called-when-use-scrolltoposition)

[RecyclerView onScrolled not being fired at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054960/recyclerview-onscrolled-not-being-fired-at-all)

[RecyclerView not calling onScrolled at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182373/recyclerview-not-calling-onscrolled-at-the-bottom)

[android RecyclerView onScrolled not call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383305/android-recyclerview-onscrolled-not-call)

https://github.com/passsy/ArrayAdapter/issues/4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative is to check if the recycler can scroll vertically if it cannot then it means it has reached the bottom.

Try this

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)

                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    // Load more
                }
            }
}

`
```

Comment: It is a good alternate solution, instead of relying on `onScrolled`. I implemented it and it is working.

Comment: It's working perfect. But when I do same in onScrolled it sometimes not working. So what's the difference between  `onScrolled` and `onScrollStateChanged` ? @itabdullah @christoandrew